# does anyone know why IDEA database view show date time with second precision only?

Tags: intellij-idea, jdbc, tdengine

I'm using IntelliJ IDEA database view to connect my databases include MySQL for relational data and TDengine for time-series data. But I found the date-time I got from MySQL show fully include millisecond but the time I got from TDengine show only second precision.

[image]

I know the TDengine JDBC connector already returns millisecond precision data. I wonder how to make IDEA support it as what it works for MySQL.

Comment: What is the column type?

Answer (score -1):

See "date_string_format" option in database connection advanced settings:
[image: advanced database settings]

Comment: unfortunately does not work. btw, only 3 'S' be accepted. If I input 6 'S', it will be changed to 3 'S' automatically.